# Python: How do I search and write to a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, input

I am trying to make a program that will ask for the user to input some information and then search for that information in a csv file. Once it has found the information I would like it to then write some more data (which was also input by the user) in the next column but on the same row.

If that wasn't clear, I will put an example below.

```
Name = input("What is your name?") # I want to search for this in my CSV file.
Age = input("What is Your age?") # I want this to be input into the next column along but still on the same row of the CSV file.
with open("Test.csv", "r") as csvfile:
csvfilereader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in csvfilereader:
    for field in row:
        if field == Name:
            print(row) # I can find and print data along the row, but I am not sure how to input data in the same row.
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Current CSV file:

```
Name    Speed
John
Jamie
Jake
```

What I want it to look like:

```
Name    Speed
John    20 #Assuming these values are entered by the user.
Jamie   15
Jake    25
```

Comment: Generally you cannot update the file in place, you will need to write out a new csv file with the updated data (look at `csv.writer`). Then delete the old file and move the new file to old the name.

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to include a sample of `Test.csv` and also how you are hoping to see it updated.

Comment: I updated my post to add the CSV files.

Comment: Use a dict aan store as json, it is a lot easier lookup with and add to keys